# Ball structuring element representation

Tags: matlab, element, representation

Regarding the `ball` structuring element mentioned [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/strel.html#bqkf9ju), how can we represent it as a matrix, the same as some structuring elements represented at the same page?

Answer (score 0):

strel('ball',radius,height)

Type this into matlab and it will display a matrix:

```
strel('ball',5,10)
```

The first matrix you get is the area and size of the ball as a matrix. The second matrix is the height of the each element of the ball.